# Distribution of $Y=\min\{X-1,0\}$ for given PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x\mathbb{1}_{[0,2]}(x)$. Find distribution  of $Y=\min\{X-1,0\}$. So CDF
\begin{align}
F_X(t)=\int\limits_0^t\frac{1}{2}xdx=\frac{1}{4}t^2 \text{ for } t \in [0,2]
\end{align}
Then

\begin{align}
F_y(t)=\Bbb P(Y<t)=\Bbb P(\min\{X-1,0\} <t)=\Bbb P(X-1<t | x\in[0,1))+\Bbb P(0<t|x\in[1,2))=
F_X(t+1) 1_{t\in [-1,0)}(t)+1_{t\in[0,?]}(t)
\end{align}

But I'm not sure how to correctly write the last line. Could you please help me? And this distribution doesn't have a PDF obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the transformation function, it is self evident that, when $x \in(1;2)$, thus with probability $3/4$, Y is constant =0 thus the resulting CDF is not absolutely continuous; in other words Y concentrates the probability of $3/4$ in the point $y=0$; in this point Y is discrete.

Thus the CDF is

$$F_Y(y)=\frac{(y+1)^2}{4}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[-1;0)}(y)+\mathbb{1}_{[0;\infty)}(y)$$

if you do a drawing of your CDF you will see a "jump" in $y=0$.
The height of this jump is the probability of the (discrete) point $y=0$

Obviously a density does not exist for this rv

Comment: why $y \in [0;\infty)$?

Comment: @displayme: as happens in any CDF's. They are always definend in $\mathbb{R}$. As an example your X CDF is

$$F_X(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}\cdot  \mathbb{1}_{[0;2)}(x)+\mathbb{1}_{[2;+\infty)}(x)$$